# Why can I integrate two differentials on the two side of an equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Suppose there is an ode:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = a(t)x
$$
Then we can solve it by following steps:
$$
\frac{dx}{x} = a(t)dt
$$
**integrate** on both side and we get:
$$
\int \frac{dx}{x} = \int a(t)dt  + C
$$
Why can I integrate differentials, what does it exactly mean by integrate a differential? Is there an elementary explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is an equation of differentials:
$$
F(x)dx = G(t)dt
$$
The equation only makes sense when $x$ is exactly a function of $t$, we denote it by $x = x(t)$, then the equation becomes
$$
F(x(t))dx(t) = G(t)dt
$$
what the equation exactly says is that
$$
F(x(t))x'(t)dt = G(t)dt
$$
namely
$$
F(x(t))x'(t) = G(t)
$$
We can integrate on both side since they are functions and there is no ambiguity, and we get
$$
\int  F(x(t))x'(t)\, dt = \int G(t) \, dt  + C
$$
And
$$
\int  F(x(t))x'(t)\, dt = \int F(x) \, dx + C
$$
is what we already know.
So we get
$$
\int F(x) \, dx = \int G(t) \, dt + C
$$

Comment: I will not say much about the most popular question on MSE why it is that we can do algebra with differentials as if they were ordinary numbers. Just this: do it and check if it solves the ODE. Regarding your way of "proving" it. It is simpler: From $dx/dt=ax$ we get $$\frac{1}{x}\frac{dx}{dt}=a$$ (fully rigorous!). Now integrate both sides w.r.t. $t$ and use the fully rigorous change of variables formula to convert the $dt$ integral into a $dx$ integral. You should also mention that the solution you get is $$\textstyle x(t)=x(0)\exp(\int_0^ta(s)\,ds)\,.$$

Comment: Even if we arrived here unrigorously we could check now that it solves the ODE.